# TTk radio button

Tags: python, tkinter

I have defined a class 'exemple' where i did two radio buttons , when i press 'bu1 ' spangender dont take any value.help me please

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class exemple():

     def like(self):

            root = Tk()
            style = ttk.Style()
            style.theme_use('classic')
            spangender = StringVar()
            rb1 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='male', variable=spangender, value='male')
            rb1.grid(column=0, row=0)
            rb2 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text='female', variable=spangender, value='female')
            rb2.grid(column=1, row=0)
            bu1 = ttk.Button(root, text='ok', command=lambda: get())
            bu1.grid(column=2, row=1)
            def get():
                print(spangender.get())#Dosen't work
            root.mainloop()
    root = Tk()
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use('classic')
    def get():
        ab = exemple()
        ab.like()
    bu1 = ttk.Button(root, text='ok', command=lambda: get())
    bu1.grid(column=2, row=1)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. Please read [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your answer to be more clear about what you are asking. You need to write precisely what is your problem, and what you have done so far to solve it, if you want people to spend time helping you.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the error is fuction get() does'nt work

Comment: Don't call `Tk()` more than once - one of the numerous problems this causes is non-working variables.